# Initialise full graph of objects when creating top level so to prevent nulls

Tags: c#

If I want to initialise an object that contains other objects, what's the best way to minimise code and prevent a null reference exception?

Example code (also at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XUmzIW)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Level1 level1 = new Level1();
        level1.Level2Prop.Level3Prop.StringProp = "A value";

        Console.WriteLine("Prop has been assigned the value:" + level1.Level2Prop.Level3Prop.StringProp);

    }

}

public class Level1
{
    public Level2 Level2Prop {get; set;}

}

public class Level2
{
    public Level3 Level3Prop {get; set;}
}

public class Level3
{
    public string StringProp {get; set;}
}
```

This code will throw a null reference exception because "Level2Prop" hasn't been instantiated.  I realise that I could instantiate "Level2Prop" within the constructor of the "Level1" class (and the "Level3Prop" within the "constructor of thr "Level2" class), but if each child has lots of object properties and the object graph is very deep, that would require lots of typing!

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use initialization via constructor, and make properties immutable (get only)

Comment: Or use property initializers.  There is no "best" way.

Comment: or maybe dependency injection (IoC container) could help. But that would require some refactoring